# How to remove an icon from the menu bar without uninstalls?

Tags: unity, icons, menu

I know, one can uninstall or blacklist a particular app or service so that it doesn't show up on the top menu bar, but is there a way you can voluntarily, and safely (without any Terminal bashing or changing the system (read uninstall)) remove an icon?

For example, I don't need Ubuntu One now, or the Mail icon. There are different ways of doing that, like uninstalling Empathy and Thunderbird, but I need those apps once a while.

So my question is: **How do I simply, peacefully, remove a certain icon from the menu bar without uninstalling or blacklisting any app or service?**

Comment: There is no "safe" and "peaceable" way. What's wrong with uninstalling Ubuntu One?

Comment: Well, intuitively, any menu bar that has icons, no matter whether it's an OS or whatever, shall have simple mechanism to add or remove an icon from it...

Answer (score -1):

you can delete the icon or name without UN-installing the application.
1--> go to menu bar
2--> right click
3--> select INTERNET or which name for the INTERNET service
4--> right side the applications list are shown
5--> just uncheck the check box of the application you want.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers).