# How to PERMANENT remove Rhythmbox, VLC etc under sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, vlc, rhythmbox

While using dconf. it temporarily removes but always reappear or reset and these media player sit just under sound menu. Ubuntu sound menu option looks like dogs tail. Never gonna be straight. I have tried several alternative method but all of them just temporary. VLC, Rhythmbox comes again under sound icon on Ubuntu 14.04

What to do? How to remove them permanently all media player under sound icon but not from system.

I have tried several method but all are temporary solution, Please give permanent solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove VLC player from sound menu in Unity bar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/468811/remove-vlc-player-from-sound-menu-in-unity-bar)

Comment: Several answers in the link do offer a permanent solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to compleatly remove programs from your system

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge "program name"
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To clear useless left over libs

Answer (score 1):

Just go to ubuntu-software-centre and in there go to installed programs and remove or un-install those programs you don't want.

Comment: It is not as simple. I want to remove them from sound settings or sound menu but not from system.

Comment: Something cannot be removed from any of the menus without complete uninstall. If you want to remove Thunderbird icon from mail, you have to remove Thunderbird. Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/511567/how-to-remove-an-icon-from-the-menu-bar-without-uninstalls